# How to get the value of the assigned by in table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a table where it shows assigned to like same way I should get assigned by

This is the stored procedure:

```
select order_id, la_name, branch, la_reference_no, order_received_dt, UserName as assignby, UserName as assignto
from neworder 
    inner join newemployee on neworder.Assign_to = newemployee.Employeeid
where Assign_to=@userid
order by order_id
```

This is my code:

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@flag", 1);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", Session["User_id"].ToString());
com.CommandText = "teamandmy_pipeline"; //Stored Procedure Name
```

How to get assignedto value[here there is assigned to and assigned by but it displays same name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3OTQ.png)

I already have the employee id stored in assignedby but it should show the name

Comment: I assume that the _newemployee_ table has the name, then just add it to the list of fields required by the SELECT statement.

Comment: `UserName as assignby, UserName as assignto`. You are putting the same value in both. Thats why you get the same name. Steve got your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the name referenced by the the *AssignedTo* field is in the table *newemployee* then you have already all the relationships correctly referenced by your *inner join*.
All you need to do is use the name field of the employee from the newemployee table.

So, assuming that this field is named **UserName** in the newemployee table you need to write

```
SELECT no.order_id, no.la_name, no.branch, no.la_reference_no, no.order_received_dt, 
       no.UserName as assignby, ne.UserName as assignto
FROM neworder no INNER JOIN newemployee ne ON no.Assign_to = ne.Employeeid
WHERE no.Assign_to=@userid
ORDER BY no.order_id
```

Notice that to disambiguate between the fields of the two tables each table has an alias after his name and this alias is used as prefix in front of the column names

Comment: i can't get your explanation @Steve can you pls edit the code according to it

Comment: else explain me in simple  way i'm new to programming

Comment: This is more basic SQL than programming. You have a relationship between the table order and employee right? the employee table contains the names of the employees right? Now you JOIN the two table using the AssignedTo field from order and EmployeeID in employee. This allows you to find the name of the employee in the employee table. You extract the name of the employee and use it in the query under your stored procedure. Note that I don't know what is exactly the column name in the employee table that contains the name. Change ne.UserName  with ne._theexactcolumname with empname_

Comment: This is basic SQL and if it is not clear for you then I really suggest to search some tutorial on the net. There are many and with basic stuff like these you canì't go wrong.